# Symfony 4 - Build-in webserver - Ignore some paths from the routing process

Tags: php, symfony, webserver

I run a Symfony 4 application using the PHP built-in web server on my development environment.

I would like the `/tmp` folder on my host to be ignored from the Symfony routing process in order to be accessed directly (and so being able to access the files within this directory).

However, when requesting `http://localhost:8000/tmp`, Symfony tries to match the route `/tmp`, which obviously does not exist. Instead I would like to get a list of the `/tmp` folder files.

I guess there is no way to handle that simply using the PHP built-in webserver and I have no other choice than using a full-featured web server, but I just want to be sure that I'm not missing any option that could actually do that just using the built-in web server ?

Comment: I dont think you will be able to access the files, and you shouldn't be. Why do you want to access them through the browser?

Comment: tmp should be under the public directory.  You really don't want to give web access to anything but the public directory.

Comment: @JoppeDeCuyper The reason I want to do that is to let the users download some generated temporary files using a link given via API. Anyway, as you and @Cerad mentioned, this is a really bad idea to give web access to anything but the Symfony public directory. Putting them into the `public` directory works. Furthermore, I'm going to check the suggestion from Roman Litvinov below. Thanks for you replies.

Answer (score 0):

Do not add your tmp folder in /public directory. If you want to use some temporary data better to hold them in /var directory and access to this folder in your controllers or services by using [Finder component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm going to check that solution too.

Comment: According to your reason I will do next: 1) create service, which control the processes of generate file and store it in tmp folder, retrieve generated file by some criterias. In this service you can use Finder Component. 2) create controller, which uses service and return the generated file as Response